# Can I use MSTSC to connect to a Terminal Services RemoteApp?

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server

I have installed Windows 2008 Terminal Services and I want to use the new RemoteApp feature, I have setup a remoteapp but I don't want to use the WebAccess to get to it and I don't want to create an .RDP file. The reason for this is my SSL VPN can connect to Terminal Services but I have to use a name and port for the connection.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in the RDP file for a RemoteApp (you can look at it in a text editor), there are special parameters such as `RemoteApplicationMode, RemoteApplicationName, and RemoteApplicationCmdLine`. These parameters cannot be set in the MSTSC GUI.

I'm not sure I fully understand why you can't use RDP files with your SSL VPN (can you clarify?), but if you are limited to only what you can type in the MSTSC GUI then you can't use RemoteApps.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've read round the subject in the last hour or so and come to the same conclusion. I'll get users to use the RDP files for now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a distribution file to install on the pc.  It will install just like any other application but connecto via RDP.  We use it for a very important application in our company.  Check out [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733174.aspx).  You can start on the Create Windows Installer Package if you have alreay gotten that far.  Let us know how we can help.